# MessageSecurityException - WCF ERROR - An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, wshttpbinding

I am working on a WCF Service and Client, both work well if there are in the same machine, with the same Certificate (also if I have one for Client and one for server).
But if I deploy the Service to IIS (as part of a Website) I get a vague error with nothing to search for, I really don't know what else to look for. All certificates in place.
I get "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party"

Server Config (ServiceModel part)

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CertificateServiceBehavior" name="ASPApplication.Service.IncomingDataService">       
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IncomingDataBinding"
          name="IncomingDataEndpoint" contract="ASPApplication.Service.IIncomingDataService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="www.testserver.com" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>       
        <behavior name="CertificateServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="www.testserver.com"
                          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                          storeName="TrustedPeople"
                          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>       
        <binding name="IncomingDataBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message algorithmSuite="Basic128"
                     clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                     negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                     establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client Config (ServiceModel part) the address is hidden on purpose

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IIncomingDataService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
              algorithmSuite="Basic128" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>        
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateServiceBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="www.testserver.com"
                          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                          storeName="TrustedPeople"
                          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <serviceCertificate >
              <defaultCertificate findValue="www.testserver.com"
                          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                          storeName="TrustedPeople"
                          x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/IncomingDataService.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="CertificateServiceBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_IIncomingDataService" contract="IncomingDataService.IIncomingDataService"
        name="wsHttpBinding_IIncomingDataService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="www.testserver.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```